# How do I disconnect internet, run software, restart internet

Tags: macros, network-programming

I don't even know if it's possible, and I certainly don't know how to do it.

```
Disconnect my internet connection
run software  (e.g. C:\notepad.exe)
Restore my internet connection when I close software
```

Thanks

Comment: There may be a service that you can start/stop that will affect the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First nothing is impossible with programming.

Create a batch file with following contents

```
@echo off
start /wait ipconfig /release
START /WAIT notepad.exe
start /wait ipconfig /renew
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me, as it did not disconnect my internet connection  (I'm using Win7)

Comment: Edited the answer, try now